# 3Dmax "user defined properties" similar in Blender

Tags: properties, custom-attributes, custom-properties

Is there a way in add 'User Defined Properties' in Blender like in 3DMax

[image: 3DMAX - User Defined Properties]

Comment: Are you looking for [Custom Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/custom_properties.html)?

Comment: No. I'm tried adding a string in the custom properties and export as FBX and try to see if it appear in the model after importing into 3dmax but I see some other sting like uv realated text.